# Flow: Specify type of the keys and values of an object

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I want to create a type for a `headers` object in which I know that the keys are gonna be `strings` and the values as well. Can I create a type that specifies the type of the keys and value of this object?

```js
export type Options = {|
  +headers?: Object,
|};
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, the keys or properties of an Object are always of type String, or Symbol. So no need to specify the type of the keys.